# save form on code behind

Tags: c#, updates

I want to save (update) a form from code behind.

I have in the edit form the buttom

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" style="color: #FF0000; font-size: medium; font-weight: 700" Text="Update" />
```

but in some cases I want to save the form automatically before firing the update button.

How can I do this on code behind?

Comment: i think you mean 'save' not 'safe'

Comment: What kind of controls do you have in the form other than your submit button?  It is hard to say what you can use to trigger update events when we don't know what is possible.

Comment: How about actually posting the code for the form? What have you already tried? What is causing a problem in what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `Timer` to the page to have ASP cause a postback on a fixed interval.  You can then attach an event handler to the `Tick` event and save the form there.

That alone would cause a full page postback on each interval; if you want to have the saving be asynchronous you can wrap the `Timer` in an `UpdatePanel` to have it do an async postback.  You could also have a label in the `UpdatePanel` as well, or some other control, to indicate that the form was saved.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="5000" ID="timer" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTimerResponse" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then in your code behind all you need is:

```
timer.Tick += (s, _) =>
{
    SaveForm();
    lblTimerResponse.Text = "Form automatically saved";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> but in some cases I want to save the form automatically before firing
>   the update button.

You can use JavaScript `interval` or `timeout` functions in order to achieve a timer functionality.

Personally, I would do it using jQuery framework, AJAX technique, `interval` and `serialize` functions.

Add the following to the `head` section in your `aspx` page (verify that `form1` is the ID of your form or change it accordingly):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text-javascript">
            var result = self.setInterval(function(){
            var $frm = $('#form1');
            $.ajax({
                type: $frm.attr('method'),
                url: $frm.attr('action'),
                data:  $frm.serialize(),
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("Success");
                }
            });
        }, 10000); // Post(update) your form each 10 seconds.
    </script>
```